# moving my sql database localhost to live server

Tags: php, mysql, database

i want to move my sql database and i have exported and imported mysql.sql file from localhost to live server and now i m not getting the files and content from that database. what i do ? i did make sure connection to database if fine and successful

here's my page http://shooop23.byethost7.com

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('','','','');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo'Database Connection Failed with following errors: '. mysqli_connect_errno();
    die();
}


?>
```

Comment: Does the DB have the content? Does the PHP get the content?

Comment: yes database have content and i have uploaded my files to my server

Comment: So what happens when you query, result is just empty?

Comment: Your sql  connect seems empty  .. you should declare the right connection  param

Comment: I guess they are intentionally omitted...

Comment: what you mean how i do that

Comment: i am not receiving anything from database please guys help me in this

Comment: Use the `@` to tag people. No notifications are sent without it. You need to debug more. What specifically fails? Is the DB connection actually live? `select now()` gives you a response?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have successfully established a connection to MySQL, you need to perform a query specifying what you want to retrieve and then subsequently retrieve it.

The following example uses [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

You should explore the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to learn the basics.

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo'Database connection failed with the following error: '.mysqli_connect_errno();
    exit;
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MyCol1,MyCol2 FROM MyTable")) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo"{$row[0]} - {$row[1]}<br>");
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$sql="SELECT * FROM login";
```

here i connected and stored my database and set a sql command (which is now a string) into these two veriables.

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo'Database connection failed with the following error: '.mysqli_connect_errno();
exit;
}
```

this is to check if the database is correctly connected, if not then it will show some errors.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
```

here i put the  database and the sql command to run my query.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $row['username'];
}
```

here finally outputting the usernames(username is one of the column in my table in this case) which matched with that query
i will suggest [This Sql site](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql.html) to get a better understanding on sql queries and try to improve the secuirty because this is the basic point where hackers try to inject their attact most offenly.
**Note : If your table's in the database are empty then it will not able to fetch anything**